# How to define a default value for a @WebParam in a java web service?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

i have been trying to find a solution for this particular topic:

It is possible to define a default value in a @webParam annotation for a SOAP/WSDL based Web Service? What i want is exactly the following result:

I Have a @WebMethod in my web service called getCustomers with the following signature:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getCustomers")
@WebResult(name = "customer")
public Customer[] getCustomers(@WebParam(name = "company") String company,
       @WebParam(name = "limitTop") int limitTop){

       //Logic of getting customer be here

}
```

Particularly, the parameter **limitTop** is not optional in this method, this number indicates how many customer records you want the response returns, but i want that in my xml schema, this particular element has a default value, something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="getCustomers">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="company" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        **<xs:element name="limitTop" type="xs:int" default="100"/>**
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Please notice the **default** attribute in the element named **limitTop**

This is in order to allow to the client application send a SOAP message without the **limitTop** element, but still limit the number of records returned to the default value given in the limitTop element.

I am using Java, JAX-WS, and GlassFish Server Open Source Edition.

Thanks for your help.

Carlo Yañez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after cannot be implemented with your current webservice style. First, JAXB will not inject the default value into the message, *if* the element is not present in the original message sent. From the [JAXB manual](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Element_default_values_and_unmarshalling.html)

> element defaults do not kick in when the element is absent, so unfortunately we can't change this behavior.

As a workaround, you could change your webservice style to `WRAPPED`. With this style, you can encapsulate your webservice parameters in a single parent type (a simple `RequestWrapper` if you will). Given that flexibility, your clients can supply a single parent type that may or may not contain both parameters. Your wrapper should look something like:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class YourWrapper {

 String company;

 @XmlElement(name="limitTop",required="false",defaultValue="100")
 int limitTop; 

//getters and setters
}
```

Also,

```
@RequestWrapper(targetNamespace="http://you.com/ws/types", className="com.you.YourWrapper") 
@WebMethod(operationName = "getCustomers")
@WebResult(name = "customer")
public Customer[] getCustomers(@WebParam(name = "company") String company,
       @WebParam(name = "limitTop") int limitTop){

       //Logic of getting customer be here

}
```

Given the above, JAXB will be able to ignore the absence of the value and possibly set the default *after* the unmarshalling

Comment: Ok, kolossus, Thank you for your help, i have your suggested solution very clear, what i don't have clear at all is the mentioned webservice style change to WRAPPED, what is supposed i should do to change my webservice style? Anyway, your answer help me a lot to clarify my doubts about this issue. Thank you again.

Comment: @CarloYañez - take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324051/webservices-bare-vs-wrapped)